# GatsbyJS with TypeScript: Get page context within a layout?

Tags: typescript, gatsby

Is it possible to access the page context from a layout in GatsbyJS?

Within my page context I've additional data which I want to use in the header, like a meta tag description or a list of translated pages.

I've tried to change the graphql query to ..

```
query={graphql`
  query IndexLayoutQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
        keywords
      }
    },
    sitePage {
      context {
        langKey
      }
    }
  }
`}
```

.. but the context is always empty.

My whole layout looks like this right now:

```
interface StaticQueryProps {
  site: {
    siteMetadata: {
      title: string
      description: string
      keywords: string
    }
  }
}

interface Props {
  translation?: Translation
}

const IndexLayout: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, translation = EnglishTranslation }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query IndexLayoutQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            keywords
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={(data: StaticQueryProps) => (
      <IntlProvider locale={translation.language} messages={translation.messages}>
        <LayoutRoot>
          <Helmet
            title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
            meta={[
              { name: 'description', content: data.site.siteMetadata.description },
              { name: 'keywords', content: data.site.siteMetadata.keywords }
            ]}
          >
            <html lang={translation.language} />
          </Helmet>
          <Header title={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
          <Main>{children}</Main>
          <Footer />
        </LayoutRoot>
      </IntlProvider>
    )}
  />
)

export default IndexLayout
```

How can I access the page context from a layout?

Comment: Can't you just pass it to `LayoutRoot ` via props?

Answer (score 0):

is's as easy as:

```
const Page = ({ pageContext }) => {
const dataNode = pageContext.yourRequiredNode;
// ......

}
```

Comment: On pages this would be correct. For a layout you need to do some prop-drilling.